# POST of '/svn/xxxx/!svn/me': 403 Forbidden

Tags: svn, commit, post-commit

Got below error. Could not find a way to fix.
Commit
Commit failed (details follow):
POST of '/svn/xxxx/!svn/me': 403 Forbidden
 (https://xxxx.net)

I checked if the url is proper, and tried after removing the saved credentials from settings and from appdata. yet no luck.

Any help in this regard is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Repository has been moved to a different location and I don't have access for it.

Requested the admin to provide the access for me. This is all you need to do.